# How to pass string variable as a parameters in javascript with single quotes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i have a MVC view which has onclick event and that calls a javascript function 
but i am unable to pass string parameter because when i click on the button it throws and error 'undefined'

Here in below code `@item.Name` is of type string. which i want to pass as single quotes.

What i understand that it requires string to be passed in single quotes.. just like the hard coded parameter 'Start'

```
<a href="#"><img alt='Start' src="~/Content/Images/icons-vm-status.png" onclick="javascript:armStatusInfo.actiononrg('Start',@item.Id,@childItem.Id, @item.Name);" />
```

Comment: You don't need to pass it in single quotes. Show you script.

Comment: try put single quote around your variable such as '@item.Name', so it will be treated as string in js

Comment: Yes this works  '@item.Name'